# C array indexing

Tags: c

I have a pretty simple question but it confuses me a bit

For example:

```
int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

I have a question asking what the value of: a + 3 is

Simple question,what I tried was just adding 3 spots so the array would start from 2 and onwards.

Comment: What do you mean by the "value of a + 3"?  Is there some specific code you're referring to?

Answer (score 4):

Value of `a + 3` is a pointer value of type `int *` that points to memory location of `a[3]` - an array element that contains value `3` in your example. That is a direct answer to the question you asked. Is that what you wanted to hear?

P.S. It is not clear what you mean by "array would start from 2 and onwards". Where did that "2" come from?

Comment: I'm _guessing_ that he's referring the 2 that is the third element of his array, but it is indeed unclear.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: Well, counting from 1, `a + 3` would point to the *fourth* element of the array, which is 3, not 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you just referenced `a`, it is a pointer to the first element of the array, so a[0] - that is, a pointer of type `int *`. Adding to the array is in most cases equivalent to adding to such a pointer, so `a+3` will refer to `a[3]` or the value 3 in your case.

Comment: Good answer. Thanks! I get it now. Basically was just asking what value in the array a+3 was referring to but I got it now. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

if you want the value of "a" then the value will be its address as array acts as a pointer and points to the first element of the array i.e. a[0]
so lets suppose the address of **a** is 0059FE8C then the address of **a+3** will be 0059FE98.

As each integer is of 4 bytes so add 4 each for each 0059FE8C +4+4+4= 0059FE98.

Now if you will do *(a+3) for int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} then this means a[3] which has value 3.

Answer (score 0):

If the starting address of your array `a` is `1000` then `a+3` would give you `1000 + 3*4`, ie, `1012` (assuming `int` is of `4` bytes). It is because array names are decayed to pointers to its first element.
Dereferencing `a + 3`, which is a pointer to fourth element of the array, would give `3` (fourth element of the array).